# Schengen visa refused using motif 2 on purpose and conditions of stay

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas

A friend of mine who is an official teacher, applied for a visa to Germany and got refused because of the motif #2 saying:

```
The purpose and conditions of the intended stay have not been established
```

The file was full of papers, the original invite from her son in law was in the file, and even a high amount of money in the bank account.

What is extended explanation of this motif and how can she pass it in her next apply.

Answer (score 1):

Just having money isn't enough. Your friend has a son-in-law in Germany who is inviting her for some time. She probably isn't young any more. A suspicious mind could wonder if she wants to move in with her daughter and family and overstay. So your fried has to explain why she wants to come to Germany and **why she will leave again.**

But there is a special case for Germany. If the son-in-law signs a formal  **Verpflichtungserklärung**, a promise to reimburse the German state for any intentional or unintentional overstay, that might make the difference in applications that might otherwise be denied. The son-in-law must have enough income to cover possible claims and may be required to post a bond.

Comment: How should he apply to `Verpflichtungserklärung` in Germany ? At the city mayor office ?

Comment: At the Ausländerbehörde at the place of residence - https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/newsroom/buergerservice-faq-kontakt/faq/13-verpflichtungserklaerung/606492